# Can't set a cookie in Chrome 5

Tags: php, cookies, google-chrome, setcookie

Since today I am facing a tricky issue with Google Chrome that I've just updated to v5.
I have a user login process running on my website. Everything works fine on FF 3.6.x and IE 7, but I just can't set any cookie in Google Chrome 5. I'm mentioning 5 because it worked very well before on v4.

My PHP script looks like that:

```
  $cook = setcookie($cookieName, $value, $expires, '/', '.'.$domain);
  var_dump($cook, isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName]));
```

I even tried the alternative `setrawcookie` without any result.

```
  $cook = setrawcookie($cookieName, $value, $expires, '/', '.'.$domain);
  var_dump($cook, isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName]));
```

FF 3.6.x and IE7 output:

```
bool(true) bool(true)
```

Whereas Chrome v5 outputs:

```
bool(true) bool(false)
```

And obviously I see not trace of this cookie in Google Chrome 5. Any idea? =/

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: Answer thanks to Imre L and ZZ Coder: do NOT prefix with a dot the domain parameter when it is an IP address. Chrome v5 does not like it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check cookies by entering `javascript:alert(document.cookie)` into address bar.

Cookie will be sent to server on 2nd request. 
`[browser request(no cookie)]->[server response(set cookie)]...[browser request(cookie, if valid)]->...` 
So you should see the cookie in $_COOKIE by refreshing the testpage.

Also check if your parameters are right. (time in future and domain is your domain)

Comment: Hi, I set up a test page like that: `setcookie('mycookie', 'value', 1275045629, '/', '.192.168.0.xxx');` and the `javascript:alert(document.cookie)` does only show me the PHPSESSID cookie. Did you try on google chrome 5 yourself?

Comment: Remove domain to see if it works. '.192.168.0.xxx' is invalid. You shouldn't add dot to IP addresses.

Comment: dont prefix IPs with a dot. It's meant for domain names for subdomain purposes.

Comment: Yeah that's the trick! thanks a LOT :) If I used the IP address it's because the website is under development on one of our server. The strange thing is that all other browsers (and 'old' chrome versions too) do NOT care about that dot.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same , check your system date and time